# Cannot connect to WebSocketServer using IP (but localhost is ok)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, websocket

This is very straightforward.  I have a WebSocketServer project that works great if the uri is `http://localhost:8081/` but if I use the local IP instead of localhost `http://10.0.0.201:8081/`, it refuses to answer requests on that IP.  I am sure its a permissions issue or unable to access the port issue but I am, frankly, not getting any errors.  It just simply doesn't respond.   Can anyone shed some light on this?   This is all in c#.

Again this is a SERVER.  It is supposed to LISTEN on 10.0.0.201 (and, of course, localhost).  Localhost works, but the IP does not from any client.

I am intentionally not posting code (although I could if necessary) because this is a multi-threaded application that supports multiple concurrent clients.  And it works flawlessly through localhost.  I am only changing the word "localhost" to the machine's IP.  The failure feels like a binding or permissions issue.

Comment: What IP is the server actually listening on? Is it listening on 10.0.0.201 or at least 0.0.0.0? Or is it listening on 127.0.0.1 instead?

Comment: Yes, it is listening on 10.0.0.201.  This is the server I am talking about.  -1 lol.  It listens fine if the uri is localhost.

Comment: In your server 10.0.0.201 is the port 8081 is open? trying using with out the post and just 10.0.0.201 and check if it the application is specifically pointed to this IP.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to Http Binding in your webserver (e.g. IIS), the binding could be explicitly requiring `localhost` and if the URI does not have `localhost` then it would refuse this connection.

Try changing the binding to empty hostname and URI should be allowed.

Comment: I am actually writing a web server and not using IIS.

Comment: Then you might want to check to what interface you're binding in your WebServer, because you could be binding to the `loopback` which will respond to `localhost` but not explicit IP.

Comment: you're testing `http://localhost:8081/` vs `http://10.0.0.201:8081/`  from the same host where your webserver is running right? not from other machines?

Comment: Yes both on the same server.  The only thing I change is "localhost" to the IP.  I stopped the w3svc just in case that was the culprit (bindings) and it still didn't change.  Interface, you mean network card/interface?  That's an idea maybe :)  Where would I specify the interface I wonder (or determine which is being bound).

Comment: @JonGlazer what are you using to write your web server? What are you instructing it to bind to when starting the listening? Please show your actual code, or a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](/help/mcve). How do you expect people to help you when you don't provide details about what you are actually doing?

Comment: I am writing the server in c# using WebSocketServer. Its a multi-threaded application that supports multiple concurrent connections (at this point, through localhost only). I am using the uri `http://10.0.0.201:8081/`; to initiate the listener. That is the only change and it doesn't work. Using the uri `http://localhost:8081/` works flawlessly. Portscanner reports listener on 8081 when I use localhost and nothing when I use the IP. It has to be a simple config or permissions issue

Comment: I think you might need to post some of that server code to really get material help.

Answer (score 0):

This is a suggestion, not an answer.  Have you tried hitting the WebServer from a different machine?  Even if it's just a static test page?
It *could* be a perms problem, but this would at least tell you if any machine on the local network can get to it using the IP/Port configuration.

Comment: Yea,  Thanks for the suggestion.  That was the first thing I tried and what clued me into the problem.   Then I tried it locally and found the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try binding to *

If using `HttpListener` try this:

```
httpListener = new HttpListener();
httpListener.Prefixes.Add("http://*/");
```

instead of

```
httpListener.Prefixes.Add("http://localhost/");
httpListener.Prefixes.Add("http://10.0.0.201/");
```

Binding to localhost will not bind to all the rest, and binding to a specific IP address will not work with localhost or IPv6 for example.